# How long is paypal order id valid?

Tags: paypal

I have a general question:
If I create an order via "`createOrder: (data, actions)`" and do not approve this "order". How long is OrderID valid?

Thanks in advance!

Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count on it being valid for 3 hours

(though the actual time before it expires can be as long as 72 hours)

If it isn't used soon after creation, you should simply generate a new OrderID whenever one is needed.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to know! Thank you for your response! :)